# Evitar la indexación de ciertas secciones de una web al crear el sitemap

Tags: java, php, seo

Buenas,

Tengo que actualizar el sitemap porque la estructura de mi página ha cambiado, sin embargo quiero evitar indexar ciertas páginas que son por así decirlo, dinámicas. Por ejemplo, tengo una sección de noticias y cada vez que pulsas sobre cualquier noticia te lleva a un `noticias.php?ID=10`, pongo 10 por poner un número, pero puede ser cualquiera.

El caso es que no consigo que el sitemap se salte ciertas páginas. Lo estoy intentando con el siguiente código en robots.txt:

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: single.php?id=*

User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: listado_precios.php?juegosPorPagina=*&Ordenar=*&Genero=*&pagina=*
```

En los asteriscos se supone que van números, pero me los indexa igualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo algunos ejemplos:

Bloquear todas las URL que incluye `?`:

- `Disallow: /*?*`

Bloquea todas las URL que tenga el parámetro `param1`

- `Disallow: /*?param1=*`

Bloquea todas las URL que tenga el parámetro `param1, param2, param3`

- `Disallow: /*?param1=*&param2=*&param3=*`

Tienes que saber también que no todos los bots aceptan o reconocen el `*` asterisco, excepto Google y Bing.

[+ info](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo he probado pero me sigue rastreando las páginas. Tengo por ejemplo una que es `single.php?ID=8`,pongo 8 pero ahí va un número, y son 2.000 en total...me rastrea muchas con esa estructura, por eso quiero bloquearlo para que no lo indexe, pero usando `Disallow: /*single.php?ID=*` me lo sigue rastreando.

Comment: @JetLagFox - No.. prueba simplemente `Disallow: /*?ID=*`

Comment: Me lo sigue indexando. Estoy usando esta página, no vaya a ser que sea por eso...[enlace](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/crawl.html)

Comment: @JetLagFox - Vale entonces cambia: `User-Agent: Googlebot` a `User-Agent: *` y me cuentas

Comment: @JetLagFox - O prueba lo con [Google Webmaster Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=es)